# log base 1 of 1

Tags: logarithms

What is $\log(1)$ to the base of $1$?
My teacher says it is $1$. I beg to differ, I think it can be all real numbers! i.e., $1^x = 1$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

So I was wondering where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Although it's the matter of convention, but usually $\log_b a$ is not defined for $b = 1$. But if you want to find a formal solution of $1^x = 1$, then you're right. Any complex power of $1$ is $1$. So the solution is $x \in \mathbb C$, or $x \in \mathbb R$ if you're working with real numbers.

Comment: Yeah but my original question was in log form. I converted it to exp form to make it more intuitive. I would appreciate if ur answers r in log formats then it would rule out any problems at that stage of conversion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason why it is not convenient to define $\log$ for the base of $1$ is simple:

$$\log_11=\frac{\log_e 1}{\log_e 1}$$

But the denominator is $0$ and thus the division doesn't make any sense unless we're working with limits :)

Comment: How is the denominator zero?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje what do you think it is?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje $\log_e1=x\implies 1=e^x\implies e^0=e^x\implies x=0$

Comment: Oops.....sorry, I get the point.

Comment: You are forgetting something. Here is Euler's identity. $e^{i}+1=0$. So $(e^{i})^2=1$. $i2$ is a natural logarithm of $1$.

Answer (score 14):

What is $\dfrac00$?  What number must $x$ be if $0\cdot x=0$?  It can be any number.

What is $\log_1 1$?  What number must $x$ be if $1^x=1$?  It can be any number.

Hence these expressions are undefined.

What is $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)=0$?  In some cases it's $6$.  It depends on which functions $f$ and $g$ are.  It can be any number or $\infty$ or $-\infty$.  But it's not always undefined.  In many cases it's defined and equal to a particular number.  For that reason $\dfrac00$ is an indeterminate form.

What is $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\log_{f(x)}g(x)$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)=1$?  Again this depends on which functions $f$ and $g$ are.  In many cases it's a specific number.  This is also an indeterminate form.

Comment: 0/0, log1(1) are the same, and tan(90), sin(90)/cos(90) and a/0 are the same. They claim it is undefined due to division but I beg to differ. It is well defined. In the slope formula (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = dy/dx = sin(t)/cos(t) = tan(t) it shows up when t = 90 or the slope approaches (+/-)infinity. For me the wording of undefined is wrong. The answer could be 0, could be 1, could be +/-infinity. Without more information and proper context we don't know thus the correct answer is that  x/0 for all x is Ambiguous not Undefined! Undefined to me means there is no definition. Ambiguous is more accurate!

Answer (score 5):

If we defined $\log_1 1$, we would want it to satisfy the basic properties that log satisfies.  One of these properties is

$$a^{\log_a b} = b$$

Well, this is bad, because setting $a = 1$, we find that $1^{\log_1 b} = 1^{\text{stuff}} = 1$, so the equation works only when $b = 1$.
But suppose we ignore this property.  There are still other properties of $\log$ we can't satisfy, like the change of base formula:
$$
\log_a {b} = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}
$$

As Sarunas nicely observes, setting $a = b = 1$ gives $\log_1 1 = \frac00$, which is bad.  But suppose we ignore this problem as well.  Then another property of logs is
$$
\log_b x + \log_b y = \log_b xy
$$

Well, $b = x = 1$ gives
$$
\log_1 1 + \log_1 y = \log_1 y \implies \log_1 1 = 0
$$

which suggests that $\log_1 1 = 0$.
But there are still other properties:
$$
\log_a a^b = b
$$
Well, setting $a = 1$, we get $\log_1 1 = b$, and this must be true for any $b$.  So we have yet another problem.

We could go on like this for ages, but hopefully you get the idea.  While you *can* define $\log_1 1$, you're going to run into problems because virtually all of the properties of logs are no longer satisfied in the way you want.

It's worth noting that in complex analysis, $\log$ in general has to be a multivalued function, i.e. since there are multiple solutions in $x$ to $a^x = b$, $\log_a b$ has multiple values.  From this standpoint, it makes a lot of sense to define $\log_1 1$ as *the set of all complex numbers* ($\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: So, moral of the story is that $\log 1 \ base (1) \not= 1$??

Comment: @SaurabhRaje That's correct -- your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Here is something interesting. 1 would have an uncountably infinite number of laogarithms to ther base 1, while other nonzero complex numbers only have a countably infinite number of logarithms to the base 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question itself is wrong at first place, because while making question you need to take care of domain of function, which in this can never be 1.

> By definition of logarithmic function, we know that base of
>   logarithmic function is a positive number excluding x =1. x>0,x≠1

So, for f(x)=logx1 
x≠1

[Source](http://cnx.org/contents/e2cd348b-c16e-4d8a-b2da-ef8a97d18671@7)

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is completely valid, $1^x = 1 $ is an equation for which the solutions are defined by the set $ \mathbb{R} $. However the function $ \log_b : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ isn't defined for $ \log_1(1) $, as the log function is only defined to return a single real number. What you're suggesting requires that the definition needs to be $ \log_b : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \{a : b^x = a \} $. Changing this definition then results in over complication and doesn't serve the use the old one does as being a component in other real valued functions, at the end of the day this is just a matter of formalisms.

Answer (score 0):

$1$ has an *uncountably* infinite number of logarithms to the base $1$. For any nonzero complex number $c$, $1$ is a $c$th power of $1$, and the set of complex numbers is uncountably infinite.

Contrast this with complex numbers other than 1. If $z$ is a nonzero integer and $i^2=-1$, then the logarithms of $c$ to the base $1$ take the form $\frac {-i\ln(c)}{2z}$. As the nonzero integers are on ly a countably infinite set, there are only a countably infinite number of logarithms to the base 1 for each $c$.

Answer (score -4):

log 1 to the base 1 is "0".
Because log a base a is 1"where a not equal 0 and a not equal 1" 
therefore log 1 base 1 is 0

Comment: $1$ has an uncountably infinite number of logarithms to the base 1 among both real numbers and complex numbers.