# Can log 1 to the base 1 be any number?

Tags: logarithms

If log 1 to the base 1 can be any number. So we can invent a new mathematical idea called the "any". If log 1(1) = "that idea", so is that wrong?

Comment: There is *not* a number which "can be any number".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log base 1 of 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413713/log-base-1-of-1)

Answer (score 3):

$\log_1 1$ is *undefined*. By the change of base formula, we can see this is equal to $\frac {\ln 1} {\ln 1} = \frac 0 0$, which is itself undefined (an indeterminate form).

Undefined or indeterminate does not mean "any number", it simply means that it is not possible to assign a proper meaning to the expression.

Comment: Completely agree that "undefined" is not equivalent to "any number". The confusion might arise from the fact that there is not one number that solves the equation - but this doesn't suggest that all numerical solutions are equally valid ("any" number), but rather that all numerical solutions are equally *in*valid ("not a number"/undefined). Log1(1) doesn't equal 1, or 2, or -73, it equals none of those.