# How to express in logarithmic form?

Tags: logarithms

If $a^x=y$, we can write $x=\log_a y$, what can we write in logarithmic form for $1^5=1$?

Comment: $a\in R^+ -  \{1\}$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413713/log-base-1-of-1

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\log_a x$ is well-defined for real numbers $a > 0$ and $x > 0$, except for $a = 1$. If $a = 1$ then $\log_1 x$ is not well-defined for any $x$ because if $x \neq 1$ then there are no solutions to $1^y = x$, and if $x = 1$ then there are infinitely many solutions.

You will notice this also relates to the change-of-base formula for logarithms:

$\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}$

If $a = 1$, then $\log_b a = 0$ which makes the right-hand side undefined.

Comment: Good point, I will edit my answer.